# JavaFXPorts jfxmobile ios task ends in FileNotFoundException

Tags: robovm, javafxports

I have a grade project which uses the jfxmobile plug-in, which I'm using with RoboVM. When I run `./gradlew ios` from Terminal in OS X, the "createIpa" task ends in the following error:

```
(etc...)
Warning: java.beans.IntrospectionException is a phantom class!
Warning: java.beans.Introspector is a phantom class!
Warning: java.beans.BeanInfo is a phantom class!
:app:createIpa FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:createIpa'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '/Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/app' does not exist

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12 mins 50.675 secs
```

`app` is a module within my multi-module grade project, and is the module using the jfxmobile plugin.

How does one resolve this? I don't know what that file or folder `/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/app` is supposed to be for, and why it's not there...

Other details that may or may not be relevant:
 - I have OS X Yosemite, XCode 7, JDK 8u40, RoboVM 1.13
 - the RoboVM builds have been taking about 15 minutes! In case that's relevant
 - I get those "phantom class!" warnings
 - Early in the build I get warnings `ld: warning: object file (/Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robovm/robovm-dist/1.8.0/7793b612873829ad0b98f82650b49bfc16b51818/unpacked/robovm-1.8.0/lib/vm/ios/thumbv7/libgc.a(thread_local_alloc.o)) was built for newer iOS version (6.0) than being linked (5.0)`
 - Previous to this large project, I was able to successfully build [this small jfxmobile project](https://github.com/voxoid0/scala-javafx-desktop-android-ios) and install it on my iPad.

**EDIT:**
Here is the --debug log output for the :createIpa task (some DEBUG entries ommitted for post limits):

```
23:06:47.646 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:createIpa (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
23:06:47.646 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:createIpa
23:06:47.649 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Executing task ':app:createIpa' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
[ . . . DEBUG entries ommitted . . . ]
  23:06:51.008 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Task] RoboVM has detected that you are running on a slow HDD. Please consider mounting a RAM disk.
To create a 2GB RAM disk, run this in your terminal:
SIZE=2048 ; diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'RoboVM RAM Disk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((SIZE * 2048))`
See http://docs.robovm.com/ for more info
23:06:51.427 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] ipa os ios
23:06:51.428 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] ipa target org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.IOSTarget@753cefb3
23:06:51.428 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] ipa archs [thumbv7, arm64]
23:06:51.429 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] ipa classpath entries [ . . . ]
23:06:51.430 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] ipa force link classes [javafx.**.*, com.sun.**.*, com.android.**.*, org.apache.harmony.security.provider.**.*, sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger, java.util.logging.**.*]
23:06:51.431 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] ipa libs [Lib [value=/Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libglass.a, force=true], Lib [value=/Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_font.a, force=true], Lib [value=/Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_iio.a, force=true], Lib [value=/Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_ios_webnode.a, force=true], Lib [value=/Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libprism_common.a, force=true], Lib [value=/Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libprism_es2.a, force=true]]
23:06:51.483 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Building thumbv7 slice
23:06:52.115 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Task] RoboVM has detected that you are running on a slow HDD. Please consider mounting a RAM disk.
To create a 2GB RAM disk, run this in your terminal:
SIZE=2048 ; diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'RoboVM RAM Disk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((SIZE * 2048))`
See http://docs.robovm.com/ for more info
23:06:52.414 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Compiling classes using 4 threads
23:07:46.773 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Compiled 0 classes in 54.34 seconds
23:07:46.810 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Linking 15716 classes (ios thumbv7 release)
23:07:48.466 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] 145128 methods out of 145128 included in the executable
23:07:55.887 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Building ios binary /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/app
23:07:56.109 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -o /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/app -arch armv7 -Wl,-filelist,/Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/objects0 -L /Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robovm/robovm-dist/1.8.0/7793b612873829ad0b98f82650b49bfc16b51818/unpacked/robovm-1.8.0/lib/vm/ios/thumbv7 -ObjC -exported_symbols_list /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/exported_symbols -Wl,-no_implicit_dylibs -Wl,-dead_strip -fPIC -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -lrobovm-bc -force_load /Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robovm/robovm-dist/1.8.0/7793b612873829ad0b98f82650b49bfc16b51818/unpacked/robovm-1.8.0/lib/vm/ios/thumbv7/librobovm-rt.a -lrobovm-core -lgc -lpthread -ldl -lm -lz -liconv -lsqlite3 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework MediaPlayer -force_load /Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libglass.a -force_load /Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_font.a -force_load /Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_iio.a -force_load /Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libjavafx_ios_webnode.a -force_load 
23:07:56.110 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task]     /Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libprism_common.a -force_load /Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libprism_es2.a -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks
23:07:56.857 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Task] ld: warning: object file (/Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robovm/robovm-dist/1.8.0/7793b612873829ad0b98f82650b49bfc16b51818/unpacked/robovm-1.8.0/lib/vm/ios/thumbv7/librobovm-rt.a(merged.o)) was built for newer iOS version (6.0) than being linked (5.0)
23:08:19.150 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Task] ld: warning: object file (/Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robovm/robovm-dist/1.8.0/7793b612873829ad0b98f82650b49bfc16b51818/unpacked/robovm-1.8.0/lib/vm/ios/thumbv7/librobovm-bc.a(bc.c.o)) was built for newer iOS version (6.0) than being linked (5.0)
 . . . [more of the same warnings] . . .
23:08:31.903 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Linked 15716 classes in 45.11 seconds
23:08:31.904 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Building arm64 slice
23:08:34.581 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Task] RoboVM has detected that you are running on a slow HDD. Please consider mounting a RAM disk.
To create a 2GB RAM disk, run this in your terminal:
SIZE=2048 ; diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'RoboVM RAM Disk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((SIZE * 2048))`
See http://docs.robovm.com/ for more info
23:08:34.928 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Compiling classes using 4 threads
23:09:17.909 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Compiled 0 classes in 42.98 seconds
23:09:17.926 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Linking 15716 classes (ios arm64 release)
23:09:19.245 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] 145128 methods out of 145128 included in the executable
23:09:26.014 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Building ios binary /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/arm64/app
23:09:26.067 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -o /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/arm64/app -arch arm64 -Wl,-filelist,[ . . . same as clang++ invokation above . . . ]
23:09:26.068 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task]     -force_load /Users/Joel/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.6/54df44d72ae88d41d5579aba19764d22c4fa4688/unpacked/ios-sdk/rt/lib/libprism_es2.a -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks
23:10:14.102 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Linked 15716 classes in 56.19 seconds
23:10:14.459 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Building fat binary for archs [thumbv7, arm64]
23:10:16.398 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/app /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/arm64/app -create -output /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/com.percebemusic.pianoapp
23:10:34.599 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Creating IPA in /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/ios
23:10:34.657 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:createIpa'
23:10:34.658 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:createIpa FAILED
23:10:34.662 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:createIpa (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 3 mins 47.015 secs.
23:10:34.662 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]] finished, busy: 3 mins 48.786 secs, idle: 0.015 secs
23:10:35.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:10:35.228 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
23:10:35.229 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:10:35.229 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
23:10:35.230 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:createIpa'.
23:10:35.230 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '/Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/app' does not exist
23:10:35.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:10:35.231 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
23:10:35.256 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:createIpa'.
23:10:35.257 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
23:10:35.257 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
23:10:35.257 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
23:10:35.258 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
23:10:35.259 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
23:10:35.259 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
23:10:35.261 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
23:10:35.261 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
23:10:35.262 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
23:10:35.262 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:208)
23:10:35.262 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:186)
23:10:35.262 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:62)
23:10:35.263 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
23:10:35.263 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
23:10:35.263 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:111)
23:10:35.264 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
23:10:35.264 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
23:10:35.265 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
23:10:35.265 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
23:10:35.266 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
23:10:35.266 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
23:10:35.266 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
23:10:35.267 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$6.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:174)
23:10:35.267 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
23:10:35.267 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
23:10:35.267 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:47)
23:10:35.268 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runBuildOperation(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:189)
23:10:35.268 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:171)
23:10:35.268 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:35)
23:10:35.269 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
23:10:35.269 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
23:10:35.270 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
23:10:35.270 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runRootBuildOperation(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:184)
23:10:35.270 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
23:10:35.271 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
23:10:35.271 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:93)
23:10:35.271 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
23:10:35.272 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
23:10:35.272 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
23:10:35.273 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
23:10:35.273 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:72)
23:10:35.273 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
23:10:35.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
23:10:35.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
23:10:35.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:10:35.275 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
23:10:35.275 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:10:35.275 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
23:10:35.276 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:10:35.276 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
23:10:35.276 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:10:35.277 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
23:10:35.277 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
23:10:35.277 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
23:10:35.278 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
23:10:35.278 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:10:35.278 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
23:10:35.278 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:10:35.279 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
23:10:35.279 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
23:10:35.279 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:10:35.280 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
23:10:35.280 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
23:10:35.300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:10:35.302 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
23:10:35.306 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
23:10:35.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
23:10:35.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
23:10:35.307 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
23:10:35.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
23:10:35.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '/Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/app' does not exist
23:10:35.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:43)
23:10:35.314 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:78)
23:10:35.314 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:226)
23:10:35.314 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
23:10:35.314 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
23:10:35.315 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
23:10:35.315 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
23:10:35.315 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
23:10:35.315 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
23:10:35.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 69 more
23:10:35.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '/Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/app' does not exist
23:10:35.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1074)
23:10:35.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1038)
23:10:35.317 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.robovm.compiler.target.AbstractTarget.doInstall(AbstractTarget.java:449)
23:10:35.317 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.IOSTarget.archive(IOSTarget.java:624)
23:10:35.317 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.robovm.compiler.AppCompiler.archive(AppCompiler.java:795)
23:10:35.318 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.robovm.compiler.AppCompiler$archive$0.call(Unknown Source)
23:10:35.318 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.ios.task.CreateIpa.createIpa(CreateIpa.groovy:63)
23:10:35.318 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
23:10:35.322 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 76 more
23:10:35.322 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:10:35.323 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
23:10:35.323 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
23:10:35.323 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
23:10:35.323 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 4 mins 7.481 secs
```

Comment: Could you try `./gradlew --info ios` and check the console for any possible exception?

Comment: Can you run on command line this: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/thumbv7/app /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/arm64/app -create -output /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/com.percebemusic.pianoapp` and `cd /Users/Joel/Documents/code/percebe/project/com.percebemusic.pianoapp/app/build/javafxports/tmp/ios` ?

Comment: yes, those ran! is jfxmobile not expecting multiple architectures or something?

Comment: And after running it, in .../tmp/ios you can find an `app` file? That was the reason I asked, the error said file not found

Comment: yes, the app file is there. so i wonder if there is a way to get the gradle tasks to cooperate on the file location... i'm new to robovm so i'm mostly waving my hands

Comment: And it is not empty? Then the stacktrace shows an error that it may not be the real reason of the problem.

Comment: not empty. it's 152MB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107338/discussion-between-jose-pereda-and-voxoid).

Comment: After fixing issues with having Java 8 dependencies, Android builds successfully, but I still get this same error with iOS/RoboVM